# datatable pagination jquery, Length menu not woring

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables, server-side

Im using [datatable](https://datatables.net/) pagination for my project, but lengthmenu not working
I am using this example for my project
http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html

my datatable is ajax

and I am using:
Codeigniter 3.1

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/web/crud/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="padding-right:0px; hidden; whitespace: nowrap;">

<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl" style="table-layout: fixed; display: block; font-size:17px; text-align:justify; max-width:100%; width:100%; margin-right:0px; font-family:BMitra; overflow-x: scroll; 
whitespace: nowrap;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color:#026B04; width:20px; max-width:20px; min-width:20px; font-family:BYekan;font-size:18px;">ردیف</th>
                   <th style="color:#9E0013; width:650px; max-width:650px; min-width:650px; font-family:BYekan;font-size:18px;">پیام</th>
                    <th style="color:#9E0013; width:20px; max-width:20px; min-width:20px;font-family:BYekan;font-size:18px;">ساعت</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
             <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color:#026B04; width:20px; max-width:20px; min-width:20px;"></th>
                   <th style="color:#9E0013; width:650px; max-width:650px; min-width:650px;"></th>
                    <th style="color:#9E0013; width:20px; max-width:20px; min-width:20px;"></th>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>

        </table>
    </div>


<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/web/crud/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/web/crud/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = $.noConflict();

jq(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = jq('#table').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('tops/posts/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    });


});

</script>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML and JS to understand the issue better.

Comment: Hard to say. There is nothing that should prevent the lengthMenu from working - is the dataTable initialised, i.e filtering and so on? The example / recipe looks fine, the demo at the end works well....

Comment: demo is good but when i use this example in my project the length menu not working, and length menu is on in this file:jquery.dataTables.min.js